# List permissions for a given role definition

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory

I found the list role assignments for my user as follows:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName <email_or_userprincipalname>
```

From the output of the command, I am given a certain *RoleDefinitionId*, let's call it **Contributor**.
How can I find all of the permissions which the **Contributor** role has associated to it?

---

I tried:

```
Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Id <id>
```

where "id" is the *RoleDefinitionId* from the previous command, but I receive an error:

> Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition : Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   does not have an implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete list can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor)

- Microsoft.Authorization/*/Delete
- Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write
- Microsoft.Authorization/elevateAccess/Action
- Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/write
- Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/delete and * for all access